# How can i import AdminClient Websphere?

Tags: java, websphere

Many examples use AdminClient interface.
I searched for a dependency in maven central repository, but did not find it there.
How can i use it, how can i import AdminClient to my project?

Comment: What's your use case?   Do you really want to use the Java interface?  Often for client admin type of usages people would prefer to use the wsadmin Jython library.

Comment: It's not in Maven central as far as I know, but if you have a WebSphere install, there is a folder called "runtimes", these are jars intended for use in a j2se environment, and one of those is, I think, admin(something).jar (?) that has the code you want.